# How can I create a function with two parameters which both can have multiple inputs or data?

Tags: python

I'm creating a tic tac toe game. I have a function that will replace the part of the board that is chosen by the user, and the computer would then make a play. The function is set-up to insert two parameters (user_choices and computer_choices). However, after the first round, I need the function to be able to take multiple choices in the user_choices and the computer_choices.

I thought using a list could solve this issue, but I guess the parameter cannot take Lists as data.

I am pretty new to coding, so I might be missing something completely obvious. Any thoughts?

```
def making_new_board(user_choices, computer_choices):
    new_board = ""
    for character in board:
        if character == user_choices:
            new_board += user_symbol
        elif character == computer_choices:
            new_board += computer_symbol
        else:
            new_board += character
    time.sleep(1)
print(new_board)
```

Comment: Look up the use of *args or **kwargs. But if you want an easier approach, I don't see how lists can't be passed in. Try them.

Comment: Functions can indeed take lists as arguments. But with your code, the statement `character == user_choices` is always `False`if `charachter` is a character and `user_choices` is a list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it like this I propose you use a 3x3 grid

```
board = []
for i in range(3):
    board.append([""], [""], [""]) # This will create a board of 3 by 3
```

You can print this using

```
for i in board:
    print(i)
```

To edit a specific peice in the board you can use this

```
board[y][x] = "O"
```

Note: the Y value goes from top to bottom and not bottom to top.